# ¿Cómo agregar automáticamente el nombre de un archivo al momento de imprimirlo mediante la impresora "Microsoft Print to PDF", en Python?

Tags: python

¿Existe alguna manera en Python, de que al momento de enviar a imprimir, por la impresora "Microsoft Print to PDF", se le pueda asignar el nombre automáticamente al archivo, sin necesidad de asignarlo manualmente y que además no se abra dicho archivo?

```
import win32api
import win32print

def export_Archivo_Pdf(archivoExcel, archivoPDF, numHoja):
    archivo = f"D:/Programa Control de Obras - MySQL/BBDD/{archivoExcel}"
    archivopdf = f"D:/Programa Control de Obras - MySQL/BBDD/{archivoPDF}"
    print(archivo)
    impresora = win32print.OpenPrinter('Microsoft Print to PDF', None)

    print(impresora)
    texto = bytes(archivo, 'utf-8')
    print(texto)
    win32print.StartDocPrinter(impresora, 1, (archivo, archivopdf, 'RAW'))
    bites = win32print.WritePrinter(impresora, texto)
    print(bites)
    win32print.EndDocPrinter(impresora)
    win32print.ClosePrinter(impresora)

    '''win32api.ShellExecute(0,
                          'print',
                          archivo,
                          win32print.SetDefaultPrinter('Microsoft Print to PDF'),
                          '.',
                          0
                          )'''
```

Este es el código que estoy intentando. La parte que está comentada, es la primera solución donde se abre el excel y me solicita que asigne el nombre del archivo de salida PDF.

Comment: Que intentaste para resolverlo por vos mismo? Como estás mandando a imprimir? Usando pyside, la api de windows? O necesitas una macro?

Comment: Estoy tratando atraves de win32api.ShellExecute y me abre el archivo excel y luego me solicita dar el nombre al archivo PDF destino.

Comment: Ahora estoy intentando con Win32print.OpenPrinter, Win32print.StartDocPrinter, Win32print.WritePrinter, Win32print.EndDocPrinter y Win32print.ClosePrinter, me hace el proceso, sin abrir el excel, y me guarda el archivo PDF, pero el archivo PDF lo crea en 0 kb y no abre en acrobat reader , osea el archivo esta corrompido, les abradeceria su ayuda, si es posible. Gracias

Comment: Encontré una posible solución en el sitio en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66422276/12913664 Sin embargo, te recomiendo evitar la api de Windows, su binding en Python tiene documentación y tutoriales pobres y funciona solo en Windows (y la solución que mencioné seguramente lo hace unicamente con excel), te recomiendo que busques alternativas como [pandas, html y pdfkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45708997/12913664), PySide o PyQt (overkill, pero tienen bien cubierto lo de imprimir), [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) para imprimir con

Comment: el programa defaulf o [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/subprocess.html) para ejecutar otros programas para imprimir